# how to read html content from assets folder in android

Tags: java, android

```
try {


    File f = new File( "file:///android_asset/[2011]011TAXMANN.COM00167(PATNA)")    ;


        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(f);
        System.out.println("_______YOUR HTML CONTENT CODE IS BELLOW WILL BE PRINTED IN 2 SECOND _______");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
         int ch;
        while((ch=fis.read())!=-1)
        {
        fileContent=fileContent+(char)ch;                 // here i stored the content of .Html file in  fileContent variable

        }
        System.out.print(fileContent);

        //}
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is my code. I want to read html content from asstes folder my file is available in asstes folder But it gives exception `FileNotFoundException`. So plz any one tell me how to read html content from asstes folder in android?

File f = new File( "file:///android_asset/[2011]011TAXMANN.COM00167(PATNA)")  ;
when i debug  f gives=   file:/android_asset/[2011]011TAXMANN.COM00167(PATNA)

plz tell me how to get corrct directory and where i m doing wrong it shud me coming file:///android_asset/[2011]011TAXMANN.COM00167(PATNA)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to load HTML file from assets in WebView

```
 webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Untitled-1.html");
```

Untitled-1.html---File name that should be save first as .html extension

**Edited**

try this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html

there is method from this doc
public final String[] list (String path)

Comment: File f = new File( "/file:///android_asset/[2011]011TAXMANN.COM00167(PATNA)")  ;

Comment: no i m able to do this i want read content of that file not display..

Comment: what do you mean you want to read tag by tag values

Comment: yup so that i can create my own html ...i mean to say that i want to retrive html source <html>  </html>,....i m able to display in java..

Answer (score 1):

You cat get InputStream by this code:

    `getResources().getAssets().open("you_file_name_goes_here");`

Comment: showing Exception File not Found Exception...

Comment: What parameter you pass to open()?

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to use

```
webview.loadUrl('file:///android_asset/htmlFile.html');
```

right?

try this i found it in a blog:

```
    static String getHTMLDataBuffer(String url,Context context) {
    InputStream htmlStream;
    try {
    if (Utils.isReferExternalMemory() && url.contains("sdcard")) {
    String tempPath = url.substring(7, url.length());//remove file:// from the url
    File file = new File(tempPath);
    htmlStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    }else{
    String tempPath = url.replace("file:///android_asset/", "");
    htmlStream = context.getAssets().open(tempPath);
    }
    Reader is = null;
    try {
    is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(htmlStream, "UTF8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // read string from reader
    final char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    int read;
    do {
     read = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
     if (read>0) {
       out.append(buffer, 0, read);
     }
    } while (read>=0);

    return out.toString();  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
    }
```

usage:

```
      String data = getHTMLDataBuffer("file:///android_asset/yourHtmlFile",this);
      webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://example.com", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Sorry for my bad english :)