# How to store .txt dictionary file in android as it is and retrieve words from it

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-widget

I am developing android app which will provide dictionary support(suggestions while typing).
So, I have a directory of 50000 words in text format(.txt).So is it possible to store and retrieve the `.txt` file as it is in android.

Please suggest some approaches

Comment: You can put that file in `assets` or `raw` folder

Comment: but how to access the file content.

Comment: @Ganesh http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/  http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/17/using-assets-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

You can put that file in `assets` or `raw` folder

To read

```
String url = "file:///android_asset/raw/filename.txt";
```

for more see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157926/1289716) answer