# Open HTML file from assets folder

Tags: android, webview, assets

I am trying to open local html file in my Android application.

The file is located under my assets folder. So I am setting a WebViewClient and loading my page into it.
But I get a "webpage not available" error.

Here is my Activity code :

```
public class LocalDialogActivity extends Activity {

    protected WebView webView;
    private static final String ENROLLMENT_URL = "file:///assets/enrollment.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_local_dialog);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.local_dialog_webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        refreshWebView(webView);

    }

    public void refreshWebView(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl(ENROLLMENT_URL);
    }
```

and the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/local_dialog_webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And i have internet permission in my AndroidMainfest.xml file that has access to the internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any help would be welcome.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you post your logcat  messages ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to read html content from assets folder in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603222/how-to-read-html-content-from-assets-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to use the below code for loading the html

```
"file:///android_asset/enrollment.html"
```

instead of

```
"file:///assets/enrollment.html"
```

Answer (score 9):

If your structure should be like this:

`/assets/html/index.html`

`/assets/scripts/index.js`

`/assets/css/index.css`

Then just do ( [Android WebView: handling orientation changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002085/android-webview-handling-orientation-changes/27020832#27020832) )

```
    if(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle() == null) { //this works only on single instance of webview, use a map with TAG if you need more
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/index.html");
    } else {
        webView.restoreState(WebViewStateHolder.INSTANCE.getBundle());
    }
```

Make sure you add

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Then just use urls

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Zzzz</title>
    <script src="../scripts/index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think, It'd better use "raw" folder. That code works properly.

```
 InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.html_file);

     try {
         int size = is.available();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
         is.read(buffer);
         is.close();
         String str = new String(buffer);
         }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
         webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

This code it working

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {
  WebView wv;

 String url="file:///android_asset/sample.html";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webUrl_WEB);



WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);


    wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    wv.loadUrl(url);
}




public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

You need to have permissions in AndroidMainfest.xml file that has access to the internet:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You need the sample.html file placed under the asset folder

Comment: thank you, but I have set the internet permission in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Download source code from here ([Open html file from assets android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2017/04/30/open-html-file-from-assets-android/))

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.deepshikha.htmlfromassets;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

WebView webview;
 ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 init();
 }

private void init(){
 webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
 webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/download.html");
 webview.requestFocus();

progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
 progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 progressDialog.show();

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
 try {
 progressDialog.dismiss();
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 });
 }
 }
```

Thanks!