# Open local html file when button clicked on android

Tags: android, html

I have a simple android screen which consists of a button as shown below

[image: Android screen with button]

I also have a local `webpage` named `webpage.html` stored within my `assets` folder on android studio.

[image]

When the `button` on the android screen is clicked, I want to open the local webpage that I have stored. If I try opening `http://www.google.com` it works just fine. But it seems to have a problem in opening any local page for now. Following is my `MainActivity.java` code snippet -

```js
//click this button to open a web page 
    public void onOpenWebBrowser(View v)
    {
        Intent webPageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        webPageIntent.setData(Uri.parse("/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/app/src/main/assets/webpage.html"));

        try {
            startActivity(webPageIntent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            // can do something about the exception.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

And here are the contents of my `activity_main.xml` file -

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="onOpenWebBrowser"
        android:text="Open Web Browser" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S - The webpage works fine when and if I open it from the outside, in a browser. Please help!

Comment: you are trying to open your local page on a default web browser app of your phone right? not on a WebView?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to use the default web browser of my phone, but I'd make do with a webView also, after I've pulled out so many of my hair strands already! @user1506104

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open HTML file from assets folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29939174/open-html-file-from-assets-folder)

Comment: Okay I shall take a look at it! Thank you for your help! @user1506104

Answer (score 0):

First add webview layout in your `activity_main.xml`

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="onOpenWebBrowser"
                android:text="Open Web Browser" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Now in `MainActivity.java`

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/filename.html");
```

This will work!

Hope this help!

Comment: It says that `webView cannot be resolved` even after I've trying a quick fix for the import, which failed. @Wilson Christian

Comment: I guess im going wrong somewhere, I get an error that says webpage could not be loaded because the file was not found! :/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this on the place of Intent:-

```
WebView wb = new WebView(this);
    wb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.htm");
    setContentView(wb);
```

Replace this dummy url path with your file path.

Hope it may help you. :)

Comment: Do I use the path `android_asset`? Coz my folder is named just `asset` @Rajshree Tiwari

Comment: @TheLuminor use your folder name "asset"

Comment: I just tried it, getting an error that says `The webpage cannot be loaded as the file could not be found` @Rajshree Tiwari Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: @TheLuminor ok can you please post your html file here , in this link :- https://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: @TheLuminor do one thing  ( replace assests with asset)"/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/app/src/main/asset/webpage.html"

Comment: Tried adding an absolute path earlier, didnt work even then! @Rajshree Tiwari

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139986/discussion-between-theluminor-and-rajshree-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

You can show a html in a text view but only if you're only doing basic HTML tagging, this will work:

```
try
{
  InputStream inputStream = getResources().getAssets().open("myFile.html");

  String html = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);

  myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html));
}
catch (IOException exception)
{
  myTextView.setText("Failed loading html.");
}
```