# Converting Html content to a pdf file

Tags: android, html, pdf

I have html file with form and canvas that need to filling by someone(include the draw on the canvas).
How to convert the html with the content **after filling form** to PDF file and save the PDF on the device?
I googled, but didn't find any good solution.

**Update**: All the html,css, js files are in assest folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[iText](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android)**

First you need to add dependency-:

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.11'
}
```

**Sample code**

```
private void createPDF (String pdfFilename){

  //path for the PDF file to be generated
  String path = "docs/" + pdfname;
  PdfWriter pdfWriter = null;

  //create a new document
  Document document = new Document();

  try {

   //get Instance of the PDFWriter
   pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(path));

   //document header attributes
   document.addAuthor("betterThanZero");
   document.addCreationDate();
   document.addProducer();
   document.addCreator("MySampleCode.com");
   document.addTitle("Demo for iText XMLWorker");
   document.setPageSize(PageSize.LETTER);

   //open document
   document.open();

   //To convert a HTML file from the filesystem
   //String File_To_Convert = "docs/SamplePDF.html";
   //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(File_To_Convert);

   //URL for HTML page
   URL myWebPage = new URL("http://demo.mysamplecode.com/");
   InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(myWebPage.openStream());

   //get the XMLWorkerHelper Instance
   XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
   //convert to PDF
   worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, fis);

   //close the document
   document.close();
   //close the writer
   pdfWriter.close();

  }   

  catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (DocumentException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }       

 }
```

**EDIT**

Below code is working for me to get `html` file from **`assests`** folder -:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.html");
InputStreamReader fis =  new InputStreamReader(is);
```

You can change

```
URL myWebPage = new URL("http://demo.mysamplecode.com/");
InputStreamReader fis = new InputStreamReader(myWebPage.openStream());
```

to

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.html");
InputStreamReader fis =  new InputStreamReader(is);
```

May, Help you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: There is a problem with your dependencies. android studio show me an error message: "Failed to resolve: com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.11" i try to search jar file but it also same problem. you have idea?

Comment: try to use  compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10' this one is working for me

Comment: I have worked with this library such a cool library for workng with pdf

Comment: What exception you need read and write permission in manifest file as well as need runtime permission if you are working above marshmallow @tal

Comment: android studio throw me FileNotFoundException.
See my update question

Comment: try this link to open html https://stackoverflow.com/a/29939389/7073808

Comment: I try this link before.. I get the error message:/android_asset/html/testForm.html: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Sorry but i think you don't understand me, I edit my question

Comment: Have your problem solved....as you mentioned in your comment...you are getting no such file or directory...then I updated my answer...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "file.pdf");
String htmlString = "html code here";
converter.convert(getContext(), htmlString, file);
```